# APK NOT INSTALLED IN OREO

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-fragments, android-8.0-oreo

when i try to install from adb it gives me this error

> Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113

this will happen only in oreo OS.

i also add this in Build.gradle

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

but this is not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out which `ABIS` you were missing from your project.
And then include them as

```
include 'arm', 'arm-v7a', 'arm64', 'mips', 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a'
```

Secondly, check if you really require `universalApk`, you can either use `minsdkversion` and `targetsdkversion` which will cover your whole range.

Comment: How to find which **ABIS** is missing..??